# Use or Abuse of the Error Monad Transformer

Tags: haskell, styles

**Background**

I am working with a monad built of a stack of transformers one of which is ErrorT.  My monad therefore implements the `MonadError` class and `throwError` is a valid statement. I want to throw and error only when a certain condition is met.  I am inclined to do the following:

```
if badCondition
  then throwError "You did a bad, bad thing..."
  else return ()
doGoodThings
[...]
```

In looking at this I think I can even generalize it to the following:

```
throwErrorWhen :: (MonadError e m) => Bool -> e -> m ()
throeErrorWhen cond err = if cond then throwError e else return ()
```

In fact this seems so obvious that I was surprised that it was not the MonadError Library.

**Question**:

Is there a better/more correct way to raise an error only is some condition is met?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's the `when` function in `Control.Monad` that evaluates its 2nd argument if the Boolean is true:

```
when :: Monad m => Bool -> m () -> m ()
```

So you get,

```
throwErrorWhen cond e = when cond (throwError e)
```

Comment: As usual I went looking for a specific solution when there was a general one staring me in the face.